# RealmSwift control reflection process

Tags: json, swift, realm

yeah, it's a solution, but not perfect for following case.

```
JSON from server
{
    id: "4",
    key: "web_banner",
    data: [
        {
            id: "11",
            title: "app",
            description: "",
        }
    ]
}
```

i use ObjectMapper for mapping, so as the JSON schema, i create the following models

```
class Advertising: Object, Mappable {

    dynamic var id               = ""
    dynamic var key            = ""
    private var   data         = [AdvertisingData]()
    {
        willSet{// **i have to do this for Store it, it will be empty in realm if not do this**
            dataList.removeAll()
            dataList.appendContentsOf(newValue)
        }
    }
    let dataList = List<AdvertisingData>()

    convenience required init?(_ map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
    key <- map["advertising_key"]
    data <- map["advertising_data"]
    }

    override class func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["data"]
    }

}

class AdvertisingData: Object, Mappable {

    dynamic var id             = ""
    dynamic var title          = ""
    dynamic var theDescription = “”

    convenience required init?(_ map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <-             map["id"]
        title <-          map["title"]
        theDescription <- map["description"]
    }

}
```

1. i must declare the data in class Advertising just for sync data to dataList,
2. i have to ignore the property data 
   this is my solution, too ugly, some good idea? 
   Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

From [Realm docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#json):

> If your JSON schema doesn’t align exactly with your Realm objects, we recommend you use a third party model mapping framework in order to transform your JSON. Swift has a thriving set of actively maintained model mapping frameworks which work with Realm, some of which are listed in the [realm-cocoa repository](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/694#issuecomment-144785299).

So just use one of this frameworks for mapping.

Comment: It's a solution, but not perfect for the case.  i have changed my question to show the case

Comment: @巩小鹏 as the initial question was changed, I suggest you to look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33804181/alamofire-objectmapper-realm-nested-objects

Comment: Thanks, i have found the best solution for me!